# Modismo o expresión que traduzca "gaslighting"

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, expresiones, modismos, psicología

El otro día aprendí un término la mar de interesante, con esa facilidad que hay en el inglés de transformar un nombre en un verbo (como *googlear*). El término en cuestión era **gaslighting** que viene a significar algo así como *tratar de hacer dudar a una persona de su realidad mediante pequeños y sutiles cambios y manipulaciones en su entorno* (tratar de volverla lo suficientemente loca para que piense que en realidad lo está) .

El contexto era una discusión sobre una serie de noticias relacionadas con Donald Trump en particular, que derivó en una discusión más general acerca de la cantidad de noticias y nueva información a la que nos vemos expuestos en la era de Internet. Tanto que a veces cuesta mucho distinguir qué noticias son legítimas, cuáles son puro engaño y cuáles son falsas símplemente con la intención de hacer dudar de otras noticias verdaderas (es decir, que si se publica algo sobre mi que es cierto pero daña mi imagen, publico ciertas noticias evidentemente falsas, para que la gente crea que la primera noticia que se publicó sobre mi, que era en realidad cierta, es falsa como las que han venido a continuación, símplemente porque hay gente mala tratando de arruinar mi reputación...).

> Gaslight <sub>verb gerund or present participle: gaslighting</sub>
>
> manipulate (someone) by psychological means into questioning their own sanity.
>
> Gaslighting or gas-lighting is a form of manipulation through persistent denial, misdirection, contradiction, and lying in an attempt to destabilize and delegitimize a target. Its intent is to sow seeds of doubt in the targets, hoping to make them question their own memory, perception, and sanity.
>
> The term owes its origin to Gas Light, a 1938 play and 1944 film, and has been used in clinical and research literature.
>
> <sub>Wikipedia en [Gaslighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslighting)</sub>

En esa obra de teatro el marido de la protagonista intenta convencerla a ella y otras personas de que ella no recuerda bien las cosas y se está volviendo loca mediante pequeñas jugarretas como reajustar el nivel de la luz en las lámparas de gas.

Estoy bastante seguro de que no hay traducción directa para 'gaslighting' en español. ¿Existe alguna expresión o modismo en español para expresar este mismo concepto de *hacer que alguien dude de la información que recibe a base de suministrarle información falsa a propósito*?

Comment: La traducción del título de la película al castellano me parece muy interesante, pues va más allá: [_Luz que agoniza_](http://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film270165.html). Por cierto, en ella sale una jovencísima Angela Landsbury. Sin duda, una película recomendable.

Comment: Yo es que vi "gaslighting" y lo que se me vino a la cabeza es "Greased Lightning". :-)

Comment: En Chile _embolinar la perdiz_ es querer confundir al contrincante con retórica enredada. No es lo que buscas pero tiene alguna relación.

Comment: @Rodrigo caramba con las perdices. En España decimos _marear la perdiz_ para algo similar: hacer perder el tiempo. El DRAE [lo recoge](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SYYx0tq), por lo que lo mismo en Chile también lo usáis.

Comment: Creo que hay un elemento mas, si me pongo a pensar en la pelicula.  Tambien el esposo le volvia muy dependiente a la esposa.  No solo sospechaba ella que se estaba poniendo cada vez peor su condicion fisica y emocional, sino que ella creia que el esposo era su salvador, y que solo se sentia pien cuando estaba con el.

Comment: gaslighting = provocación

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La literatura médica especializada está acostumbrada a emplear la expresión `hacer luz de gas`. Algunas de las fuentes que encontré (quizás necesitarás estar en una universidad para acceder a ellas): [1](http://gredos.usal.es/jspui/handle/10366/56235) [2](https://idus.us.es/xmlui/handle/11441/51008) [3](http://www.investigacion-psicopedagogica.org/revista/articulos/18/espannol/Art_18_337.pdf) [4](https://idus.us.es/xmlui/handle/11441/39835?show=full)

Pero hacer luz de gas es nada más que hacer alguien creerse loco. Fuera de un contexto altamente específico (quizás un grupo de apoyo para víctimas de abuso doméstico), no hay necesidad de más explicaciones.

Comment: Interesante, así que resulta que el término existe tal cual (traducción literal) en español. Debí haber supuesto que en psicología se tomaría prestado el término, pero nunca habría adivinado que se usa "hacer" en lugar de "manipular" luz de gas o así. Muchas gracias.

Comment: 2. En gran parte de América, especialmente en México y el área centroamericana, se ha extendido el uso del verbo transitivo accesar (del ingl. to access) con el sentido de ‘acceder [a información o datos contenidos en un sistema informático]’: «El lector puede accesarla [la información] mediante un buscador que funciona con palabras claves» (Nación [C. Rica] 7.4.97). Se trata de un anglicismo innecesario, que debe sustituirse por el verbo intransitivo español acceder: El lector puede acceder a la información mediante... (http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=acceder)

Answer (score 5):

Tal vez no sea exactamente lo que buscas, pero tomando como referencia tu definición original:

> tratar de hacer dudar a una persona de su realidad mediante pequeños y sutiles cambios y manipulaciones en su entorno

me acuerdo de algunos videojuegos de temática de terror, en los cuales a veces pasan cosas raras, del estilo de algo que estaba en un sitio de repente ya no está, o cosas que no se comportan como cabría esperar (desafiando las leyes de la física o similar, como que algo no se refleje en un espejo). La expresión que suelo usar cuando pasan estas cosas es que el juego **me está rayando**.

> **[rayar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VEy3neE)**
>
> Del lat. *radiāre* 'despedir rayos'.
>
> 5. tr. coloq. Trastornar o volver loco. U. t. c. prnl.

Obviamente, esta expresión es demasiado coloquial (o incluso puede que regional, no sé en qué zonas se conoce y en cuáles no) como para usarla en contextos formales, pero se puede usar perfectamente así:

> —¡Tío, no me rayes!

cuando alguien te está intentando confundir o incordiar.

Comment: ¡Buena! En las zonas de España de habla catalana se usa mucho.

Comment: En Colombia algunos decimos "ese tipo tiene un rayon en la cabeza" para expresar que está loco.

Comment: Vaya, pensaba que se debía utilizar "rallar" con "Ll", (por su 2ª acepción). Tenía más sentido para mí que fuera "sufrir como si te rallaran el cerebro cual queso en un rallador", más que algo que tuviera que ver con "rayas".

Answer (score 3):

En México el modismo que más se acerca es **chorear**. En México significa mentir con el propósito de engañar o manipular ya sea para hurtar, hacer una broma o hacer dudar a una persona de sus propósitos o decisiones.

> Eso que me dices es puro **choro**

Answer (score 3):

Me bastó leer un par de noticias en inglés con el verbo «gaslight» (como «I was being gaslighted») para animarme a proponer soluciones aquí. La idea, bien explicada al principio, consiste en intimidar al interlocutor con tergiversaciones para hacerle entrar en duda; es un tipo de abuso emocional, también llamado abuso ambiental (si me permiten el arrojo), con fuente en https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Gaslighting

Según la sintaxis del texto con el cual se lidia, uno puede recurrir a diferentes soluciones, pues hay angloparlantes que modifican el significado de «gaslight» con fines personales, ya sea para exagerar o hiperbolizar una cuestión. Si bien me parecen simpatiquísimas las expresiones regionales, el problema que tenemos en el español estadounidense es adoptar una expresión que cumpla dos requisitos: es inteligible para el hablante casual y no es espánglish (que ése si lo odio con toda el alma).

Por ejemplo, veamos este texto de Psychology Today: «The first stage is disbelief: when the first sign of gaslighting occurs. You think of the gaslighting interaction as a strange behavior or an anomalous moment. During this first stage, things happen between you and your partner, or your boss, friend, family member, that seem odd to you.» (fuente: https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/power-in-relationships/200905/are-you-being-gaslighted). Ahí me parece claro que se habla de manipular a una persona por los métodos más expedientes para el manipulador. A secas, la pareja que te hace entrar en dudas te está manipulando. No es necesario dar con rodeos para incluir largas expresiones. Espero que esto les ayude. Gracias.

Nota: soy traductor profesional y me encanta investigar estos vericuetos.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, y encantados de tener por aquí a un traductor profesional, ya que en muchas ocasiones nos encontramos con preguntas del tipo "cómo se dice X en español" y nos vendría bien tu ayuda. Sin embargo, no me queda claro con tu respuesta cuál sería el término o expresión a usar si quisiéramos decir "gaslighting" en español. ¿Sería "abuso ambiental"? ¿O simplemente "manipulación psicológica"?

Comment: Las lenguas no funcionan como listas de términos equivalentes. Si tenemos 'perro' por 'dog', es más por coincidencia y porque se trata de una entidad concreta (un ser vivo --> un animal --> un perro). Para conceptos abstractos, se hace más peliaguda la cosa. Muchos gerundios en inglés, como 'bullying' o 'gaslighting', se resisten a un límpido etiquetado en español. En nuestro idioma, nos referimos a esos conceptos abstractos (ya sé, 'bullying' tiene consecuencias bien tangibles y contundentes) con frases, cosa que frustra a más de un aprendiz de español.

Answer (score 2):

Si te sirve de algo, soy de Argentina y últimamente los medios de comunicación hablan mucho del tema, y siempre usan la palabra inglesa *gaslighting* directamente. Lo mismo se hace con otras similares, como por ejemplo, *bullying* o *grooming*.
En Argentina hay una frase que es "hacer(le, me) la psicológica" que significa algo así como tratar de manipular, confundir, hacer angustiar o enojar a alguien, pero nunca vi que se usara para el gaslighting. Para referirse específicamente a este problema solo he visto usar la palabra inglesa.

Comment: Me encantó "hacerme la sicológica"! Muy coloquial, pero muy comprensible! La comenzaré a usar en México! Yo también soy intérprete traductor profesional!

Answer (score 2):

Con base en que el acoso es todo delito causado por el uso constante de conductas contra otra persona para lograr la destrucción mental y tergiversación es toda interpretación falsa de un suceso; entonces,

Pienso que el significado de "gaslighting" puede ser denotado con:

**Acoso por tergiversación**.

---

Como comentario adicional, conjeturo que el término para denotar el concepto podría ser:

**Tergiacoso**

Comment: Oilut, you may want to check …[I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

Exposición; "*El término en cuestión era gaslighting que viene a significar algo así como tratar de hacer dudar a una persona de su realidad mediante pequeños y sutiles cambios y manipulaciones en su entorno*"

---

El término "gaslighting" simplemente a sí expuesto, se encuentra dentro de una voz en Español que se ha extendido desde su comienzo en el S. XVI y XVII y que ya incorpora ciertas acepciones más actuales, si bien con ciertos matices pero que en general recoge estas conductas de manera general que aparecen para el gran público a partir de la obra de 1938 y su adaptación a la pantalla de la película "Gaslight" en 1944.

Así en cierto sentido "gaslighting" es lo que llamaríamos en algunos contextos como "**Iluminado**". Una persona "Iluminada" puede ser una persona que se encuentra en la posesión de determinadas verdades ó posee ciertos intereses inconfesables y que hace lo posible para llevarlos a cabo. El "Iluminado" puede ser el principal de una secta, pertenecer a la misma ó ser una persona simplemente que realiza los modos y formas que estas llevan a cabo para conseguir sus fines.

Un "Iluminado" ó el que hace de "Iluminado", tiene en la manipulación su principal instrumento. De esta manera cualquier parte de la realidad puede tergiversarla para convertirla en una mentira absoluta sobre unos mismos hechos. Igualmente un "Iluminado" puede negar cosas que se sabe que se dijeron o incluso afirmar que tales hechos nunca sucedieron, achacándolos a otras conductas ó comportamientos que no tienen nada ver pero que los justifican. Utilizan una sutil violencia verbal para desacreditar y alejarse de ciertas realidades que no interesan, pero sin llegar, en la mayoría de las ocasiones a la violencia ó confrontación física .

Sus víctimas pueden ser tachadas de "locos/as" medrando y erosionando lentamente las diferencias y conexiones entre lo que es real y lo que está en su propia cabeza. Un "Iluminado/a" suele intentar aislar a sus víctimas.

Todas las conductas y el proceso de manipulación que el "Iluminado" lleva a cabo, puede tener unas consecuencias catastróficas para la persona ya que puede caer en depresión y otros problemas derivados de salud mental que pueden conducir directamente al suicidio.

Existen otros términos más generales como "Maquiavélico", igualmente a considerar, aunque el término "Iluminado", se ajusta más a ese tipo de personaje concreto que no tiene que caer solo en la parte de una secta, sino que el sentido puede ser más amplio.

Al igual que Dios ilustra el interior de sus criaturas, los Iluminados intentan iluminar y manipular, con las ideas del propio Iluminado, el interior de aquellos que caen bajo su personalidad ó actitud mental.

---

Por último y por antonomasia, cualquier Donal Trump, Putin, Joe Baden, estrella ó personaje público pueden considerarse o referirse a ellos como "Iluminados", juzgados así por una parte de la sociedad. Igualmente aquellos que manipulan y juegan con los datos en general son otros iluminados, que intentan aprovecharse y dirigir las cuestiones y asuntos que llevan hacía su propios intereses. En definitiva un "Iluminado" es cualquiera que atiende principalmente a sus propios intereses manipulando y aprovechando cualquier ocasión sin ninguna consideración. En este sentido tenemos expresiones como "Por favor, Ilumíname" ó "no me Ilumines tanto".

Espero haya servido. Saludos.
Diego M.