# ¿Existe alguna palabra en Español para la acción de "manipular a una persona para hacerla creer que debe dudar de su propio criterio"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

En Inglés existe la palabra "gaslighting" que significa:

"Manipular a una persona para hacerla creer que debe dudar de su propio criterio"

Si buscas traducir este término con un traductor te va a dar la traducción literal: "iluminación de gas". Obviamente nada que ver con el significado que se le da en Inglés en el sentido explicado en el título.

¿Existe alguna palabra en Español para la acción de "manipular a una persona para hacerla creer que debe dudar de su propio criterio"?

Comment: Look here: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19390/modismo-o-expresi%C3%B3n-que-traduzca-gaslighting

Comment: @Paribus Ceteris :lol: Cuál es el aporte de colocar el mismo enlace dos veces? Pensé que habían encontrado un nuevo término.

Comment: @cocteau no fui yo, fue la plataforma...

Comment: OK, quería agregar que eso de acoso por tergiversación le di un +1 :D Saludos, aunque no hay un símil que suene tan natural, el concepto reprogramación o tortura creo que engloba demasiado, porque incluso se puede tomar como tomadura de pelo que no es tan grave como lo anterior.

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde se no existe tal palabra. En español solemos ser descriptivos al hablar. Esto quiere decir que no hay palabras que tengan un significado tan amplio.

En lo personal no usaria la palabra `manipular` para tu frase. Pienso que lo más apropiado seria `influyo` o `engaño`.

`Influyo en una persona para hacerla creer que debe dudar de su propio criterio.`

`Engaño a una persona para hacerla creer que debe dudar de su propio criterio.`

Finalmente, recuerda que al igual que en el ingles y en cualquier otro idioma el contexto en que se usan las palabras define su significado.